# VBScript / VBA / Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have over 70 Excel files with macroses in them, Excel files are set up to run after I open them and then they are closed by itself after all procedures are done. I created vbs script that open them and then close and everything works perfect. Additionally, I created a list of Excel files that VBS run and placed it in a separate Excel file, my question is how to create VBScript that would record time when every Excel file was open through VBS script.

### For one file

```
Option     Explicit
Dim oExcel, oSheet

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.workbooks.open "C:\Docum..............\data.xlsm"

Set oSheet = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)


oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.sAVE
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
oExcel.Quit

Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

---

OR for "i" number of files

---

```
Option Explicit
Dim filePath(1)
Dim oExcel, oSheet
Dim i

filePath(0) = "C:\Docum..........\data.xlsm"
filePath(1) = "C:\Docum..........\data1.xlsm"
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

For i = 0 To 1
oExcel.Workbooks.Open (filePath(i))

Set oSheet = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
oExcel.Run "macro1"

oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
oExcel.Quit
Set oSheet = Nothing
Next
Set oExcel = Nothing

Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "1"
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Your vbscript is quitting Excel after processing only one workbook: move that line after the For..Next loop.  Can't figure out what your main question is asking...

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive question title than "VBScript / VBA / Excel". Also, your question is unclear. What is it exactly you want to happen? Please remove all extraneous details as they are confusing everyone.

Answer (score 2):

> how to create VBScript that would record time when every Excel file was open

Your question isn't very clear (where do you want to record the time?), but:

- VBScript has a function "Now" that will return the current date/time
- Excel exposes an object model which will allow you to save the time somewhere in the workbook.
- VBScript has an object `Scripting.FileSystemObject` which you can use to open a file and write the current time.